# How to implement stochastic pooling in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Keras still doesn't support any built-in function for stochastic pooling. But I need to use it in my model. How can I implement stochastic pooling and use it in my CNN model in Keras? I am using Keras with Tensorflow backend.